# Internal compiler error: Segmentation fault while installing a python library

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, gcc, gnu

I have Ubuntu 14.04.
I was trying to install a python library (deepdish)
when I execute the command `sudo python setup.py install` I get the following errors.

```
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: internal compiler error: Segmentation fault (program collect2)
```

I am facing similar type of 'internal compiler error' while trying to install or make other things. I think there is some problem that has occurred in my system. Something seems to have gotten corrupted. I cant figure out the reason. Probably has got something to do with gcc or build-essential.

Following is the detailed output :

```
$ sudo python setup.py install

running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing requirements to deepdish.egg-info/requires.txt
writing deepdish.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to deepdish.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to deepdish.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
reading manifest file 'deepdish.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
writing manifest file 'deepdish.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg
running install_lib
running build_py
running build_ext
building 'deepdish.plot.resample' extension
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c deepdish/plot/resample.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/deepdish/plot/resample.o
In file included from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:1761:0,
                 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:17,
                 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/arrayobject.h:4,
                 from deepdish/plot/resample.c:258:
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h:15:2: warning: #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by " "#defining NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION" [-Wcpp]
 #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by " \
  ^
In file included from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:26:0,
                 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/arrayobject.h:4,
                 from deepdish/plot/resample.c:258:
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/__multiarray_api.h:1629:1: warning: ‘_import_array’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
 _import_array(void)
 ^
In file included from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ufuncobject.h:327:0,
                 from deepdish/plot/resample.c:259:
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/__ufunc_api.h:241:1: warning: ‘_import_umath’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
 _import_umath(void)
 ^
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/deepdish/plot/resample.o -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/deepdish/plot/resample.so
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: internal compiler error: Segmentation fault (program collect2)
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.8/README.Bugs> for instructions.
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 4
```

**EDIT**

I tried the following things :

```
$ ldd /usr/bin/gcc
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff5d7fe000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f2c8ba69000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f2c8be74000)

$ catchsegv usr/bin/gcc
/usr/bin/catchsegv: 58: /usr/bin/catchsegv: usr/bin/gcc: not found



$ ls -lah /usr/bin/gcc*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    7 Apr  8  2014 /usr/bin/gcc -> gcc-4.8
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 566K Mar 20  2014 /usr/bin/gcc-4.7
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 758K May 15 00:24 /usr/bin/gcc-4.8
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   10 Apr  8  2014 /usr/bin/gcc-ar -> gcc-ar-4.8
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  23K Mar 20  2014 /usr/bin/gcc-ar-4.7
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  27K May 15 00:24 /usr/bin/gcc-ar-4.8
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   10 Apr  8  2014 /usr/bin/gcc-nm -> gcc-nm-4.8
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  23K Mar 20  2014 /usr/bin/gcc-nm-4.7
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  27K May 15 00:24 /usr/bin/gcc-nm-4.8
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   14 Apr  8  2014 /usr/bin/gcc-ranlib -> gcc-ranlib-4.8
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  23K Mar 20  2014 /usr/bin/gcc-ranlib-4.7
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  27K May 15 00:24 /usr/bin/gcc-ranlib-4.8
```

Comment: You may be running into this issue. Check this out http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1059011

Comment: I tried the following things :

`$ ldd gcc` and got 
`ldd: ./gcc: No such file or directory`
 also tried 
`$ catchsegv gcc` and got 
`gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.`

Comment: It looks like `gcc-4.8` was recently installed. I'd suggest purging `gcc-4.8` and reinstall it. Do try using `gcc-4.7` to check if you will get the same issue.